# BitTorrent client that shows download and upload speed graph?

Tags: bittorrent

uTorrent on Windows shows an informative download and upload speed graph. Is there any BitTorrent client for Ubuntu that displays such information?

Answer (score 1):

Try Vuze, It is availiavle in ubuntu software centre..